# Javascript regex to detect CSV file type?

Tags: javascript, regex

There seems to be a lot of questions asking for regex to detect a CSV file type, but none for javascript.

Given that a regular expression for images looks like `/^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/`, does anyone know what the same would look like for CSV?

**Edit** To be a little more clear, looking for both a "how-to" to regex check if file is a CSV and the common extensions associated. Thanks!

Comment: Note that checking for file extension is not sufficient to securely identify the file type; it varies by platform but generally it's possible to give any sort of file any name with any extension.

Comment: Are you asking (1) what are the possible extensions for CSV files, or (2) how do you create a regular expression to look for them?

Comment: My bad I guess I was a little vague, basically I'm asking both. How to create a robust regular expression that can handle most common file types for CSV (looks like only 1...)

Comment: If you're just looking to see if a URL represents a csv file, then a Regex is fine; if you want to confirm that the file associated with that file is actually a CSV, you'll need to do more work, probably checking the mime-type

Comment: Understood, I'll probably use a little of both to 1) check the extension using @tskuzzy's solution on the client and 2) check MIME-type server-side. Thanks for reminding me of MIME-type ;)

Comment: Checking the MIME type on the server is only as robust as the code used by the server to determine it. On systems that simply map from the file extension to a MIME type, it doesn't really do any good. You have to open up the file and look at the bytes, or else use some tool that does (like, for example, the Linux `file` utility).

Comment: @Pointy although we're off-topic from the question, do you know of any good java/scala libs that do just that? (I'm an import n00b)

Comment: @DeLongey I'm sorry but I don't; I'm so used to using UNIX/Linux with it's `file` command that I just don't think about it much.  Well now that I think of it, a very limited tool that works from Java (big hack) is a library that provides an interface to the "image magick" command line suite from Java.  But that's only really good for images.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The CSV file extension is typically `.csv`. So try matching against that:

`.+(\.csv)$`